# Issues of List mapping by automapper

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

Im using automapper to object conversion where source is table class and destination is property class.

I'm using .dml to connect database.
App type - Window 
Using platform - VS-12 framework 4.5 , automapper version 4.2.1

**Issues :- when convert single class object automapper successfully converted but when im using list then it return zero.**

**In Config class-**

```
public static Initialize();

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, destination>().ReverseMap();
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Source>, List<destination>>().ReverseMap();
```

**In code-** 
//It run successfully

```
Mapper.map(result, objdestination);
```

//It not run work and anot giving any exception

```
Mapper.map(listresult, listdestination);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to define a mapping from List<source> to List<destination>, this should automatically be handled by the initial (single) mapping

Answer (score 0):

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>   
    {  
       cfg.CreateMap< Source, destination>().ReverseMap();   
    });   
     config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();  // check if configuration valid.    
     IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();  
     var appProduct = mapper.Map<List<destination>>(sourceObj);
```